# How can I open IE windows maximized c#

Tags: c#

im using this line to open a IE window, is it posible in code to get it to open in maximized state?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"IExplore.exe", "www.google.com");
```

or control where it opens say like

```
IEWINDOW.location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) with a [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) object which has a [`WindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) property. You can set that property so that the window starts maximized.

Adapted from the example at `Process.Start`:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
startInfo.Arguments = "www.google.com";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```